# I can't use MySQL in Windows Linux Subsystem

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, windows-10

I entered Windows Linux Subsystem with:

```
C:\> bash --login
```

Installed MySQL as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

When I try the following:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
```

I get:

```
Error 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Comment: 1. You don't need to use `sudo` to access MySQL; 2. During MySQL installation, is there any error? What if you issue `sudo service mysql restart` in shell? 3. Is the network port 3306 in use?

Comment: 4) Did you try searching (either via Google or here) for that error message? Oh, wait! You didn't need to - the possible duplicates were shown to you when you were writing your post, and several of those are on this very page in the **Related** list to the right. Over there --->>>, right below the job ads. Here's an idea: Read some of those now to see if they help. All you have to do is click the links.

Comment: 2. When I install mysql-server I get "initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused" and "runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory" and "invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop"

Comment: When I try "sudo service mysql restart" I get an error that starts with initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused"

Comment: 3. When I run "netstat -tln" I get nothing so I don't think 3306 is in use.

Comment: 1.  It is actually working now without sudo, i.e. "mysql -u root".  I swear there have been situations in which I could not access mysql without sudo, but I am glad it is working now.  Thanks Raptor!

Comment: try login by tcp instead of unix socket

Answer (score 4):

use like:

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --password=root
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the mysql service isn't running. You can start it with:

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

Answer (score 1):

Use TCP/IP connection instead as shown below:

`mysql --protocol=tcp -uroot -ppassword`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found that this works for me:

```
mysqladmin -u root password "<enter_new_password>";

mysql -u root -p
```

This will prompt you with the password you created